# FutureBuilder weird behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a FutureBuilder which the future is this :

```
Future<Tutor> future(Object? args) async {
    print("running future ...${args}");

    String title = "";
    String content = "";

    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (args != null) {
      debugPrint("args is not null ");

      title = (args as Tutor).title;
      content = args.content;

      await prefs.setString("title", title);
      await prefs.setString("content", content);
    } else {
      debugPrint("reading from cache..");

      title = prefs.getString("title") ?? "";
      content = prefs.getString("content") ?? "";
    }

    return Tutor(title, content);
  }
```

```
  return FutureBuilder(
        future: future(args),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          WebViewController controller = WebViewController();

          debugPrint("Future is done ...");
       // the rest
```

But what I get is :

> running future ...null

> (2) Future is done ...

I don't get any of this prints:

```
debugPrint("args is not null "); // if
debugPrint("reading from cache.."); // else
```

It seems neither "if" nor "else" are executed.

Comment: `future: future(args),` is broken.  Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this problem was solved auttomatically after one day but I should mention for next googlers that I also encountered this in another project and I figured that FutureBuilder has a inner error handler so it doesn't throw exceptions if something goes wrong with your "future" method. If you want to see what is what, you should always use try{}catch{} inside the future method or check snapshot.hasError to see if everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I used your code, both `debugPrint("args is not null ")` and `debugPrint("reading from cache..")` can be printed, please recheck your console.

Also, I think you should judge `snapshot.connectionState` in `FutureBuilder`'s `build` callback to make sure you're doing the right thing in the right state.

[image]

Comment: I'm using VSCode. Yesterday I got bored and turned off the computer. Today the code worked without any changes. I think hot reload was not working properly. Anyway, thanks for your time